# How to use django model clean() method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, verbose_name="Name")
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name="Direction")
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/res/{self.slug}'

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.name   
    
    
    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError        
       
        if len(str(self.phone))<=5:
            raise ValidationError({'phone':('Enter Correct number.')})
```

clean() method is not working. My view.py code is as follow :

```
class RestaurantView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset=Restaurant.objects.all()
    serializer_class=RestaurantSerializer

    def get(self,request):
        query=self.get_queryset()        
        serializer=RestaurantSerializer(query,many=True)        
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self,request):
        serializer  =   RestaurantSerializer(data=request.POST)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            name=serializer.validated_data.get('name')
            direction=serializer.validated_data.get('direction')
            phone=serializer.validated_data.get('phone')
            r=Restaurant()
            r.name=name,
            r.direction=direction,
            r.phone=phone
            r.save()
            response={'msg':'Data Saved Successfully'}
            return Response(response)
```

How can I handle the clean() method validation? I'm also validating data in serializer.py file but still i want to validate data in models clean() method.Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Validation of django objects ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)):

> There are three steps involved in validating a model:
>
> - Validate the model fields - `Model.clean_fields()`
> - Validate the model as a whole - `Model.clean()`
> - Validate the field uniqueness - `Model.validate_unique()`
>
> All three steps are performed when you call a model’s `full_clean()`
> method.

So your method `clean()` is correct, you just need to call it before saving your model instance (it is not automatically called).

This can be done be just calling `r.clean()`, or you can do a full validation (the 3 steps mentioned above) by calling `r.full_clean()`.

So in your code add the validation call before `r.save()`:

```
...
r = Restaurant()
...
r.full_clean()
r.save()
...
```

Comment: Also, remove the comma at the end of the line `r.name=name,`

Comment: What is the correct way then? I don't understand from Django doc. Can u please explain if possible.How to use clean() method